# Simple Haskell Code List of numbers

Tags: list, haskell

I don't know why this code does not run. I just simply wanted to fill 0's with a number like 4 and return the results. I am new in Haskell sorry if my question is very basic.

```
fill [] = []
fill (x:xs) = if x==0 then 0 else 4 : fill xs

 main = do
  fill [0,1,0]
```

Comment: Your code, if it did run, would do the opposite of what you say.  It would turn `[0,1,0]` into `[0,4,0]`, where you *say* you want to replace 0 with 4, so that `[0,1,0]` would become `[4,1,4]`.  Which result do you really want?  It would be helpful if you showed the desired *output* from a given input, then there would be less ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's see what the compiler is actually looking at when it sees your function `fill`:
(I don't have ghc at my disposal right now, but it should look something like below)

```
> :t fill
fill :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a] -- or fill:: [Integer] -> [Integer] for simplicity
```

Okay, that's a function that takes a list of numerics to return another list of numerics. Let's look at main:

```
> :t main
main :: IO ()
```

Wait, what's `IO` doing there? Well, `main` the entry point for all standalone haskell programs. It exposes your functions out into the real world modelled by the poorly named `IO` wrapper.

Now, what did you actually want to accomplish here?

> I just simply wanted to fill 0's with a number like 4 and return the
>   results.

Right, so let's get down to it. Here's my type definition - all I'm saying is that, whatever be the type of lists that I get here, characterised by `a` - it should conform to numbers, that's what I mean why I constrain the types to `Num`. `Num` here is a typeclass, which you can look more about [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/types-and-typeclasses#typeclasses-101).

```
fill :: (Num a) => [a] -> [a]
```

Now, when I see an empty list, I return back an empty list. Easy -

```
fill [] = []
```

In your function definition, you're not replacing zeroes at all - let's fix that:

```
fill (x:xs) = if x == 0 
              then 4:fill xs 
              else x:fill xs
```

Okay, we're still not done here - how do we expose `fill` to our outside world? Cometh the main, cometh the world. Cheesy, I know :-) But `main` wraps everything into an `IO`, how do we wrap our little function into it? Ah, how do I display strings out into `IO`? [`putStrLn` or `print`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6-latest/html/libraries/base-4.6.0.1/Prelude.html#g:26)?

```
main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn "Hello World!"
```

We're now safely esconsced in our little echo chambers muttering "hello world" to ourselves. 
Let's make it a bit more useful. Now, I'm just going to print out our list:

```
> :t print
print :: Show a => a -> IO ()
```

Like `Num`, `Show` is also another typeclass. I leave you to figure this out as homework. :-)

```
main = print $ fill [0,1,0,1]
```

which prints:

```
[4,1,4,1]
```

Comment: Amir, S.R.I's answer is comprehensive and very good.  If you wanted an exercise in writing such a function, this is how to do it.  But it is also important to know that what you are attempting is probably best done with map.  `map (\x -> if (x == 0) then 4 else x) [0,1,0,0,3,0]` would give `[4,1,4,4,3,4]`.  Learn the power of `map`; it's a key function.

Comment: @itsbruce, thanks for the kind words. I knew map would work very well here - but, since OP had a problem correctly coming up with a program, I figured I'd walk them through the thought process than going the sophisticated route. That's why I used the word 'wrapper' instead of dropping the 'M' word. :-) I gave them a few things to work out before they fully grasp the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
fill [] = []
fill (x:xs) = if x==0
              then 4:fill xs
              else x:fill xs

main = do
  putStrLn $ show (fill [0,1,0])
```

When you check for 0, you should just not return `0` but along with `0` you should call the function `fill` recursively.

And in main function, `show` is used for taking a type and returning the String equivalent for it so that it can be printed in the do block.

Comment: You don't seem to have noticed the bug in the OPs code and you've replicated it.  He *wants* to replace 0s with 4s, but

Comment: Ah, didn't notice that. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap `if-then-else` in parentheses:

```
fill [] = []
fill (x:xs) = (if x==0 then 0 else 4) : fill xs
```